# Laravel Echo with React and Pusher?

Tags: php, reactjs

Im trying to use Laravel Echo with Pusher and React, however I get "Pusher is undefined" in the console. My Code is:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

import Echo from "laravel-echo";

declare global {
    interface Window {
        Echo: Echo;
        Pusher: any
    }
}
import Pusher from "pusher-js"

if (!window.Echo) {
    window.Echo = new Echo({
        broadcaster: "pusher",
        key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
        cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
        wsHost: window.location.hostname,
        wsPort: 6001
    });
}
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement).render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

I have tried requiring it in window.Pusher but that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

Just import Pusher, like this:

```
import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
```